# Automorphism group of cyclic group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

Prove that the automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(C_n)$ of a cyclic group of order $n$ is  isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$

---

I know that the automorphism group consists of all the homomorphisms  from the group to the group. And I know that somehow I need to use the fact that the group is cyclic and has a generator. But I can't quite put the puzzle together.

Let $\langle g\rangle $ be the generator, it exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $g^m=1$ so an automorphism must do $f(1)=1=f(g^m)=f(g)...f(g)=(f(g))^m=1$ does that mean $f(g)$ is also a generator ?

In order to have an isomorphism, I need to consider a homomorphism. Let $\varphi:\operatorname{Aut}(C_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_n}$ with $\varphi(f)=$ ?

That's how far I go, automorphism are new to me and the whole exercise confuses me a little bit.

Comment: See **Theorem 6.5** of Gallian's, *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.

Comment: No, automorphisms must be ISOmorphisms

Comment: @Shaun thanks will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one place where I think it is very helpful to first ponder the problem in slightly more generality.  Fix a generator for $C_n$ once and for all.  I'll call it $g$ to meet your notation, so $C_n = \langle g \rangle$ throughout.

First, prove that every *hom*omorphism $f: C_n \to C_n$ is uniquely determined by the value $f(g)$.  I think you know how to do this.  You just need to prove that given homs $f,h$ we have $f=h$ if and only if $f(g)=h(g)$.  This is nothing more than the definition of *cyclic group*.

Next, prove that every *hom*omorphism $f: C_n \to C_n$ can be associated to a unique integer $m$ with $0 \leq m \leq n-1$.  The association is:  given a hom $f$, we know that $f(g) \in C_n$, but $C_n$ is generated by $g$.  Thus $f(g)$ is expressible as $g^m$ for some **unique** power $m$ with $0 \leq m \leq n-1$.  Let's call this $m_f$ instead of $m$ to denote its dependence on $f$.  In short, $f(g)=g^{m_f}$ where $m_f$ has been chosen "correctly."

You should be able to check that the association $f \mapsto m_f$ defines a perfectly good function from the set of all homs $f: C_n \to C_n$ into $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (as sets only for the moment).

Here's the first of two crucial moves:  prove that given two homs $C_n \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}C_n\stackrel{h}{\rightarrow} C_n$ we have $m_{h\circ f}=m_h m_f \bmod n$. That is, our association $f \mapsto m_f$ respects composition in a multiplicative way mod $n$.  This is easier than it looks.

Here's the final bit.  Prove that $f: C_n \to C_n$ is an *auto*morphism if and only if $m_f$ has a multiplicative inverse mod $n$.  To show one direction, suppose $f$ is an automorphism.  Then as $f$ is surjective there must be an $a \in C_n$ with $f(a)=g$.  This $a$, however, is expressible as $a=g^k$ for some integer $k$, since $g$ generates $C_n$.  Then
$$
g=f(a)=f(g^k)=f(g)^k=(g^{m_f})^k = g^{m_fk}.
$$
Hence $g^{m_fk}=g^1$ so you now have that $m_fk \equiv 1 \bmod n$, which is what we wanted to show.  You can fill in the rest.

Note that the association $f \mapsto m_f$ gives your isomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(C_n) \to \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ and it is now clear why the operation must be multiplication mod $n$ (because the operation in the automorphism group is composition).

Answer (score 2):

> I know that the automorphism group consists of all the homomorphisms from the group to the group.

Notice that automorphisms are not arbitrary homomorphisms, they are isomorphisms (homomorphisms+ bijections).

> Let $<g>$ be the generator, it exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $g^m=1$ so an automorphism must do $f(1)=1=f(g^m)=f(g)...f(g)=(f(g))^m=1$ does that mean $f(g)$ is also a generator ?

I want you to first show that an isomorphism preserves the order of an element (infact it preserves every group theoric properties.) Then you can conclude that a generotor must be sent to a generotor.

In the next step, just try to understand when you assign a genorator to another one, actually you assign all elements to one another. Then you can explicitly obtain the rule of your map.

Comment: I will try again tomorrow, it's getting late, and I am tired. I will post here my solution if I figure it out

Comment: If you could verify my answer, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think to prove the exercise is enough to show that

1. $|\text{Aut}(C_n)|=|\mathbb{Z_n}^*|$
2. $\text{Aut}(C_n)=<f(g)>$

---

For 2. We can check that for a generator $g$ of $C_n$ we can get every element $h=g^m ,m\in \mathbb{N}$ so $f(h)=f(g^m)=(f(g))^m$

and for 1. a $g^i$ generates $C_n$ if and only if $\operatorname{gcd}(i,m)=1$.

$\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(C_n)\rvert=\phi(m)$ where $\phi(m)$ is Euler's function.

Comment: The line $\mathrm{Aut}(C_n)=\langle f(g)\rangle$ makes no sense.  Especially since $ \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ usually isn't cyclic.  Also, $f(g)$ is an elment of $C_n$ by your notation, so how can it generate $\mathrm{Aut}(C_n)$?

Comment: My idea was that  this true of every isomorphism $f$ so one  must generate the others. Also, it's helpful when you make a comment  to explain why this is wrong or give a hint. It's like someone is confused about something and  tries to understand it, and you comment "you are wrong"

Comment: I've tried to explain.  Since the automorphism group typically isn't cyclic, it would be wrong to write it as a cyclic group generated by some element $f(g)$.  Also, if a group $G$ is cyclic it will be generated by one of its own elements, not an element from a foreign group.

Comment: @Randall Your intentions maybe are good, but your comment "sounded" rude to me. (maybe it's my fault because I am confused and can't figure it out. Anyway). I appreciate the effort. Maybe the exercise is too advanced for me since we haven't talk about the group $Z_m^*$ and automorphism yet

Comment: Honestly not trying to be rude.  Was trying to ask questions to lead you to the right path.  Apologies either way.

Comment: @Randall alright, my mistake.   When I solve it, I will post it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130701/discussion-between-lupus-nox-and-randall).